# Supervisor not detecting services

Tags: centos, installation, service, supervisord

I almost read all questions about supervisor, nothing works

OS : Centos 7
SuperVisor : 3.1.4 (Installed Via yum)

```
[root@271-appdevelopment-box supervisord.d]# systemctl status supervisord
● supervisord.service - Process Monitoring and Control Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/supervisord.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-10-09 13:57:49 IST; 1s ago
  Process: 3170 ExecStart=/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3171 (supervisord)
   CGroup: /system.slice/supervisord.service
           └─3171 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

Here are tail of  `/etc/supervisord.conf`

```
;[include]
files = /etc/supervisord.d/*.conf
```

I have my processes in /etc/supervisord.d/

```
.
├── gogs.conf
└── ngrok.conf
```

Content of ngrok.conf

```
[program:ngrok]
    command=/usr/local/bin/ngrok start --all --config=/etc/ngrok/ngrok.yml
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    stopsignal=QUIT
```

I have tried

```
# supervisorctl update

# supervisorctl reread
No config updates to processes

# supervisorctl add ngrok
ERROR: no such process/group: ngrok
```

Comment: systemd has made supervisord obsolete. There is no need to use it unless you are working with legacy programs that start with supervisord.

Answer (score 4):

Try to uncomment **;[include]** inside your **/etc/supervisord.conf** file. Also, you may want to change 
`files = /etc/supervisord.d/*.conf` to `files = /etc/supervisord.d/*.ini`

Once it's done, go to /etc/supervisord.d/ and change your filenames from .conf to .ini (for example, gogs.conf will now be gogs.ini and so on).

Then, just execute **supervisorctl update && supervisorctl reread** and **sudo supervisorctl** should display the output of your running processes.

Comment: I really don't know how i missed it. **How can i miss to uncomment header?** so silly of me.. but you really saved a tons of time! Thanks!